# How to best expose ocaml library to other languages?

Tags: ocaml, saas

There are various exchange languages - json, ect - that provide an ability to quickly and reliably export and parse data to a common format. This is a boon between languages, and for it there is [Piqi](http://piqi.org/), which basically generates parsable exchange formats for any type that you define; it automates the process of writing boiler code (writing functions that read in some exchange info and build up a instance of some arbitrary type). Basically, the best option to date is protocol buffers, and I absolutely want, if I go down the route of ocaml-rpc, to use protocol buffers.

It would be nice if there were some declarative pattern to manage function exposure, so that the ocaml library can be reached over some medium (like RPC, or map a function to a url with encoding for arguments).

Imagine offering a library as a service; where you don't want to or can't make actual bindings between every single pair of languages. But servers and the data parsing has already been written... so wouldn't there be some way to integrate the two, and just specify what functions should be exposed and where/how?

Lastly, it appears to me that protocol buffers is a mechanism by which you can encode/decode data quickly, but not a transport mechanism... is there some kind of ocaml-RPC spec or some ocaml RPC library? Aren't there various RPC protocols (and ergo, if I try to point two languages using diff protocols at one another, achieve failure)? Additionally, the server mechanism that waits and receives RPC calls is (possibly) another module(?)

**How do I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update this, the latest efforts under the piqi project are aimed at producing a working OCaml RPC service. From this, it would be, in vision, easy to specify what functions to expose at the RPC service end, and target function selection on the client side should allow for some mechanized facility to allow those exposed functions to be selected.

At the current time, this RPC system for ocaml facilitates inter-language exchange of data that can be reconstructed by parsers through the use of proto-buffers; it is under development and still [being discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/piqi/SR7Dd7yqC8E)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [ocaml-rpc](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-rpc/) library suits your requirements. It can infer serialization functions and, also, can generate client and server code. The interesting part, is that they use OCaml as a IDL language. For example, this is a definition of the `rpc` function:

```
external rpc2 : ?opt:string -> variant -> unit = ""
```

From which there will be inferred server and client functorized code, that will take care on transporting marshaling and demarshaling the data, so that you need to work only with pure OCaml data types.

The problem with this library is that it is barely documented, so you may find it hard to use.

Also, as now I know, that you're tackling with BAP, I would like to bring your attention to a new [BAP 1.x](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap), that will be ready soon, and it will have bindings, that will allow to call it from any language, although currently we're mostly targeting python.

Comment: I need any other language to reach the ocaml service, that's why I mentioned REST, in particular, I was talking about ways to make my library accessible over the network in the easiest way possible.

Comment: @AdamMiller, I've changed my answer, since now I understand your requirements. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ah man, bap 1.x? I was wanting to help and release my code into each of piqi and bap for proper modularity, but im already using piqi to provide serve bap. It is now a matter of releasing it for others. Is there any way i could contribute?

Comment: sure, we're always welcome contributions, like pull request, or just request or advice made through our issue tracker.